# How to change the location of Vim `spellfile`?

Tags: vim

Under `utf-8` encoding and  `set spell spelllang=en_us`, pressing `zg` when cursor is on a "wrongly spelled" word (as recognized by the spell-checker) will add the "good word" to the following file in my system: `.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add`.

Is there a way to change the location of this `spell-file`? It is a pain syncing all my "good words" across multiple machines. Ideally, re-directing such `spellfile` to a sub-folder in Dropbox shall solve the problem. Yet, I have not yet found documentation for this.

Comment: `:help spellfile` tells you how to do this.  This article is probably good too: https://codeyarns.com/2015/09/30/how-to-make-spellfile-in-vim/

Comment: Hi @jszakmeister, indeed, the verbal description in the `:help spellfile` does tell me what to do. I will post my implemented solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution for Windows machine `Gvim`

The following specification works with Gvim on my Windows machine:

```
set spell spelllang=en_us spell
    set spellsuggest=fast,20 "Don't show too much suggestion for spell check.
    set spellfile=c:\Users\llinfeng\Dropbox\Tool\Vim_Spell_add\en.utf-8.add
```

It appears that the `set spellfile` only take on `*.add` file per `spelllang`. (To make the change of `spellfile` effective, simply adding an arbitrary good word (`zg`) shall refresh the whole thing.)

Now, my spell file synchronizes nicely through Dropbox, across my Windows machines.

### Solution for macOS 10.12.1, for MacVIM `mvim`

```
set spell spelllang=en_us
     set spellsuggest=fast,20 "Don't show too much suggestion for spell check.
     set spellfile=~/Dropbox/Tool/Vim_Spell_add/en.utf-8.add
```

### Solution for Linux machine, for both `vim` and `gvim`

```
set spell spelllang=en_us
     set spellsuggest=fast,20 "Don't show too much suggestion for spell check.
     set spellfile=~/Dropbox/Tool/Vim_Spell_add/en.utf-8.add
```

Answer (score 0):

I keep my custop spell files in a folder which is synchronized among many systems with git (using GitLab), and place symlinks to them in ~/.vim/spell/

If you want any details, I will expand this answer.